# Ошибка при добавлении нового ключа и значения в словарь

Tags: python

Создай функцию who_is_online, которая принимает список friends словарей и определяет кто из них online, offline или away. Если пользователь имеет статус online, но его не было в сети более 10 минут (lastActivity > 10), то можно считать, что практически его статус уже away.
Результат должен быть таким:
{ "online": ["Alice"], "offline": ["Lucy"], "away": ["Bob"]}

Если в чате нет активных юзеров то результат такой:{"offline": ["Lucy"], "away": ["Bob"]}

Если друзей вообще нет в чате то тогда тогда в функцию передается пустой список , и функция должна вернуть пустой список.

Написал функцию, но она выдает ошибку KeyError: 'away'

```
def who_is_online(friends: list) -> dict:
    new_dict = {}
    for dictinary in friends:
        current_status = dictinary["status"]
        if current_status == "online" and dictinary["lastActivity"] > 10:
            current_status = "away"
            if current_status not in new_dict:
                new_dict[current_status].append(friends["username"])
    return new_dict

friends = [{
  "username": "Alice",
  "status": "online",
  "lastActivity": 10
}, {
  "username": "Lucy",
  "status": "offline",
  "lastActivity": 22
}, {
  "username": "Bob",
  "status": "online",
  "lastActivity": 104
}]

print(who_is_online(friends))
```

Comment: во-первых, нужно задать собственно вопрос. А во-вторых, добавить в вопрос что ожидается на выходе и полный текст ошибки. В-третьих, очевидно, что если в словаре отсутствует ключ current_status, то и присоединить к нему ничего нельзя.

Comment: В теле письма указан желаемый результат. Ошибка также указана????

Comment: Спорим, что текст ошибки намного длинее, чем " KeyError: 'away'". А желаемых результатов указано два. Какой из них нужен?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konstantin/PycharmProjects/su_hw_12/extra_09.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(who_is_online(friends))
  File "/home/konstantin/PycharmProjects/su_hw_12/extra_09.py", line 8, in who_is_online
    new_dict[current_status] += dictinary["username"]
KeyError: 'away'
Результат должен быть разный в зависимости от  полученных значений.

Comment: Вы прочитали "в-третьих" в самом первом комментарии?

Comment: Прочитал, может вам и очевидно, но мне, видимо не очевидно, если я обратился за помощью...

Comment: у вас отсутствует new_dict[current_status], даже есть специальная проверка! а вы пытаетесь туда что-то присоединить. Даже не так - вы пытаетесь присоединить туда что-то именно в том случае, когда new_dict[current_status] отсутствует

Comment: Как мне выйти из этой ситуации, не совсем понимаю?

Comment: Если я убираю проверку и пытаюсь добавить ключ и значение все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Вы не пытаетесь добавить ключ. Вы пытаетесь изменить существующий ключ ,который не существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from typing import Dict


friends = [
    {
        "username": "Alice",
        "status": "online",
        "lastActivity": 10
    }, {
        "username": "Lucy",
        "status": "offline",
        "lastActivity": 22
    }, {
        "username": "Bob",
        "status": "online",
        "lastActivity": 104
    }
]


def effective_status(data: dict):
    if data.get('status') == 'online' and data.get('lastActivity') > 10:
        data['status'] = 'away'
    return data

def who_is_online(user_list: list):
    users: Dict[str, list] = dict()
    for elem in map(effective_status, user_list):
        users[
            elem.get('status')
        ] = users.get(
        elem.get('status'), []
        ) + [
            elem.get('username')
        ]
    return users

print(
    who_is_online(
        friends
    )
)
```

---

```
{'online': ['Alice'], 'offline': ['Lucy'], 'away': ['Bob']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо этого: `new_dict[current_status].append(friends["username"])`

Написать вот так: `new_dict[current_status] = friends["username"]`

Comment: Ошибка TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
То что вы указали по идее перезаписывает значение, а мне нужно добавлять значения если их несколько.

Comment: @Константин Так не получится как Вы хотите. По причине того, что в Python да и в любом другом языке структура данных такая как хеш-таблица коей является словарь не может иметь в себе два одинаковых ключа. Возможно это из за своей вредности хеш-таблица себя так ведет, а возможно из за того, что когда Вы обратитесь к этому ключу она не будет знать какое значение Вам вернуть. Вот как-то так.

Answer (score -1):

```
def who_is_online(friends: list) -> dict:
    if len(friends) > 0:
        print ("Список не пуст")
        new_dict = {}
        for line in friends:

            if line["status"] == "online":
                if line["lastActivity"] > 10:
                    current_status = "away"
                    new_dict[f'{current_status}'] = s=[f'{line["username"]}']
                else:
                    new_dict[f'{line["status"]}'] = s=[f'{line["username"]}']
            else:
                new_dict[f'{line["status"]}'] = s=[f'{line["username"]}']

        return new_dict
    else:
        print(" Список пуст")
        return []

friends = [{
  "username": "Alice",
  "status": "online",
  "lastActivity": 10
}, {
  "username": "Lucy",
  "status": "offline",
  "lastActivity": 22
}, {
  "username": "Bob",
  "status": "online",
  "lastActivity": 104
}]

print(who_is_online(friends))
```

Вывод:

```
{'online': ['Alice'], 'offline': ['Lucy'], 'away': ['Bob']}
```

Comment: Не так. Ключ - статус, а не имя.

Comment: ну а ничего что ключи должны быть уникальны?

Comment: Да, нужно что бы ключом был статус, а к ключу были значения как список имен

Comment: Как потом данные достаёте из словоря?

Comment: По условиям задачи нужно только добавить список имен к ключу статусу

Comment: Хорошо как звучит дословно задание?

Comment: Создай функцию who_is_online, которая принимает список friends словарей и определяет кто из них online, offline или away. Если пользователь имеет статус online, но его не было в сети более 10 минут (lastActivity > 10), то можно считать, что практически его статус уже away. Результат должен быть таким: { "online": ["Alice"], "offline": ["Lucy"], "away": ["Bob"]}

Если в чате нет активных юзеров то результат такой:{"offline": ["Lucy"], "away": ["Bob"]}

Если друзей вообще нет в чате то тогда тогда в функцию передается пустой список , и функция должна вернуть пустой список.

Comment: # Смотри очень простой пример
my_dict = {'aaa': 40, 'aaa': 40, 'aaa': 30, 'bbb': 40, 'bbb': 30, 'bbb': 40}
pprint.pprint(my_dict)
print(my_dict["aaa"])
# Вывод
{'aaa': 30, 'bbb': 40}
30

Если не секрет кто загадал такую задачу?

Comment: На обучающих курсах

Comment: Задача больше теоретическая чем практическая

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться что за сия светительсво? с названием Школы проводящей курсы.

Comment: да они не очень известные start up it

Comment: Я конечно то ещё нубас но по какому списку будет проверятся задание когда нет юзеров онлайн?  тут можно только домыслить условие что когда все статусы будут офлайн. ещё момент опять же если только домысливать и изворачивать под решение в списке никогда не будет ситуации когда в сети 2 человека 2 офлайн и 2 авк. Авторы от бога. Даже условия задачи не могут изложить адекватно и учат примерам которые как шубу в трусы заворачивать. Щас перепишу под домысленную логику.....

Comment: Поправил пример прогоняй.....

Comment: Всё в задаче понятно изложено. Ключ - статус, значение - список пользователей.

Comment: Ну так и как тогда... решение правильное?

Comment: да нет, конечно же. Измените у Alice время на 11, например.

Comment: то получится ситуация когда ключи словаря не уникальный, что тут пробовать.